# Forcing refresh of a dhcp lease on an Ubuntu client

Tags: dhcp, ubuntu-12.04

My Ubuntu 12.04 VM (in VirtualBox) has an IP of 10.0.0.67, I have deleted the lease in the DHCP server and set a reservation for 10.0.0.64.

Despite multiple restarts, turning off and on the ethernet interface multiple times, it still holds on to its lease of .67.

How can I force it to drop the .67 lease and get the one actually now in the DHCP server?

I've tried `sudo dhclient` but it errors with:

```
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service utility, e.g. service smbd restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart job, you may also use the reload(8) utility, e.g. reload smbd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the answers worked, so I just had to end up specifying a manual IP and setting an exclusion in the DHCP scope.

It looks like the problem was that every time the Ubuntu VM requested a lease, it was requesting the IP it had previously, despite my deleting all the entries in the /var/lib/dhcp folder. There was numerous lease bits in there but nothing seemed to change what one it got again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this first of all in terminal.

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

You can also try few other commands too.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and for Server edition

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Answer (score 0):

The DHCP client running in your VM also saves a copy of its lease, probably in /var/db/ or /var/lib/db3/. Stop the client, find the latest lease and delete it, then restart your client.